# airflow not recognize local directory ModuleNotFoundError: No module named

Tags: airflow

my project structure looks like :

```
my_project
 -dags
 -config
```

however on airflow dashboard I see an error `Broken DAG` pointing to this line : `from config.setup_configs import somemethod`

and yields this err:

```
Broken DAG: [/usr/local/airflow/dags/airflow_foo.py] No module named 'config'
```

although the directory exists

Answer (score 9, accepted):

According to [documentation](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/modules_management.html#additional-modules-in-airflow) Airflow has, by default, three directories to path

- AIRFLOW_HOME/dags
- AIRFLOW_HOME/config
- AIRFLOW_HOME/plugins

Any other path has to be added to system path, as described in [airflow module management](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/modules_management.html)

For sake of simplicity, I added my module `mymodule.py` to AIRFLOW_HOME/plugins and I can import them successfully.

```
from mymodule import my_method
```

So, in your case, if you rename `configurations` to `plugins` and update import statement into DAG,

```
from setup_configs import somemethod
```

it should work.

Comment: I do get the following ```Broken DAG: [/usr/local/airflow/dags/airflow_foo.py] No module named 'config'
``` I updated my question accordingly

Comment: `config` directory is already in path. Change import statement to `from setup_configs import somemethod`

Answer (score 2):

You need to move the `config` directory into the `dags` folder and create an empty `__init__.py` file within the `config` folder. Then, it should work.